# Installing Spacy on Python 3 with Windows 10 fails at installing Preshed

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

Followup question to [This last post here about another problem installing spacy directly from source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477800/installing-spacy-for-nlp-with-python-3-windows-gives-error-when-installing-fro)

On its website, spacy gives the option to install directly from source (pip and conda are both failing, I've had slightly more luck with this way). It gives 5 steps to enter in the command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
```

`cd SpaCy`

`export PYTHONPATH=pwd`

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

I had to modify step 3 to use SET, and then it seemed to run okay. However, when I type in step 4, I get this error message:

```
Command "c:\users\jacqu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jacqu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bo29last\\preshed\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jacqu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wve_7ck8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jacqu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bo29last\preshed\
```

It seems to be a problem installing some part of Spacy called preshed. I have no idea what this error means or how to work around it. In the past I've tried to install the specific parts that I get this error for one at a time, but that doens't seem to work for preshed (pip install preshed also fails with the same  error message). If it matters at all, Spacy has a folder on my computer, so it seems to have at least partially installed.

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated - python is 3.7 and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Cannot install module spaCy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483235/python-cannot-install-module-spacy)

Answer (score -1):

What is your version of pip? I had to update pip to the latest version (from 9.x to 10.0.1) for the installation using pip to work.

Comment: Pip is version 10.0.1.  It works fine installing other things, but unfortunately not spaCy :(