# Install problems with spacy under Windows 10

Tags: spacy

I get the following errors https://pastebin.com/0veYUYuh

Whenever I use:

```
'pip install spacy'
```

Please help?

Comment: Hope this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483235/python-cannot-install-module-spacy), and which python version are you using?

Comment: Hi Adam, i tried those solutions and unfortunately they did not work. I am using Python 3.8 (64-bit) and I made sure that pip and setuptools are updated to the newest version.

Comment: Hi, i think you are using latest python release that is why it is happening, can you switch to 3.7 (64-bit) or create some environment?

Comment: That has crossed my mind because I installed spacy on my office computer which has Python 3.7 and it didn't show any errors. I will revert back to 3.7 and try installing it again.

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: Yes, I just reverted back to Python 3.7.5 and spacy installed without any issues. Some of its dependencies are probably not compatible with 3.8 which caused the issue. Thanks for your help Adam.

Comment: No problem, just up vote the comment for other users.