# Installing spaCy for Unity?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, spacy

A plugin called ["Python For Unity"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@2.0/manual/index.html) lets Unity run python programs and have them integrated into the Unity app. It uses Python 2 which is less than ideal which brings me to my question of:
How do I install spaCy, a python module where I can only find Python 3 versions of? The exception being [lfd.uci.edu](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#_spacy) which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483235/python-cannot-install-module-spacy). Though, the installation for all the 2.x modules fails at installing module "thinc" with the following error message:

- building 'srsly.msgpack._unpacker' extension
- error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

---

- ERROR: Failed building wheel for srsly
- Failed to build blis srsly
- ERROR: Could not build wheels for blis, srsly which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

How do I proceed?

Comment: Did you try installing Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0? Stepping back a bit though, you might find it easier to rely on an external server (even one running on the same machine) that uses modern Python rather than trying to get unsupported Python 2 working.